# IC identification - Analog Devices with top marking S 1E

Tags: identification, surface-mount

What is this IC from a board I should repair? IC is from Analog Devices, I suppose.

[image: Photo of IC marked S1E]

It could be a buffer or similar. It is marked as S 1E. The IC has 8 pins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could get reference from Manufacturer [ADG465 / ADG465BRM](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG465.pdf),  this is a line surge protector. Now all makes sense, usual analog 8-pin ICs have inputs pins 1...4 and outputs other side. Thanks all readers for your interest.

Comment: Andres - Hi, Thanks for coming back with the answer to your question. In order to effectively mark the topic as solved, please consider "[accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)" your answer (click the "tick mark" next to your answer, to turn it green). That shows that you don't need more help and future readers can quickly see that this was the confirmed solution. Thanks.